# Rails 4, Ajax causing a 404 and 500 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-404

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, **[Section 12.2.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax)**, and I've come across a weird 404/500 error after following his tutorial exactly as instructed.

I don't know enough about this particular error to know how to fix it.

The error occurs when trying to switch from a standard follow and unfollow button to an Ajax enabled follow/unfollow button.

The **follow** button just produces repeated 500 errors. (See Image)

[image: Follow Button]

The server console looks like this after a click on the Follow button:

```
Started POST "/relationships" for ::1 at 2015-11-21 10:42:41 -0500
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nUhePXUdztraIcRVmQ6ewMjzLBPLbCJKjvGUExoQu7XH+zTJYj9J/+wopP7kAI1ycAa5t0bG7fEuApgAQqcDDw==", "followed_id"=>"4", "commit"=>"Follow"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("followed_id", "follower_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["followed_id", 4], ["follower_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-11-21 15:42:41.359403"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-21 15:42:41.359403"]]
   (3.4ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered users/_unfollow.html.erb (7.6ms)
  Rendered relationships/create.js.erb (10.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__unfollow_html_erb__4478734189885612533_2206022220'
  app/views/relationships/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_create_js_erb___3841425439351308004_2234925000'
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

The **unfollow** button upon it's first click produces an 500 error and then on subsequent presses a 404 error. (See Image)

[image: Unfollow Button]

The server console looks like this after a click on the unfollow button:

```
Started DELETE "/relationships/106" for ::1 at 2015-11-21 10:44:16 -0500
Processing by RelationshipsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MQQWiFHmikzre6tgsaVNf25z1r4Ps4yMhiX6BVAHvWFrt3x8RsQNad1yy8vMq17N1oZDGoIZQzcm1vYWCLAF2w==", "commit"=>"Unfollow", "id"=>"106"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Relationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Relationship Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ? AND "relationships"."followed_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["follower_id", 1], ["followed_id", 4]]
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.3ms)  DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."id" = ?  [["id", 106]]
   (571.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered users/_follow.html.erb (7.3ms)
  Rendered relationships/destroy.js.erb (10.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 608ms (ActiveRecord: 574.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users__follow_html_erb__4224173111585839618_2218160400'
  app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__follow_html_erb__4224173111585839618_2218160400'
  app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_destroy_js_erb___1536758446230344516_2256927580'
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
```

In Chrome developer tools, revealing the piece of code that triggers the errors is this line:

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

I'll structure the question in two parts below... what was working prior to adding the ajax enabled buttons, and the code additions that started to produce the error.

---

### WAS WORKING: STANDARD BUTTONS

This is what was working before switching to Ajax:

**relationships_controller.rb**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

**_follow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>                        
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**_unfollow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

All tests pass.
**following_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class FollowingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user  = users(:michael)
    @other = users(:archer)
    log_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "following page" do
    get following_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.following.empty?
    assert_match @user.following.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.following.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "followers page" do
    get followers_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.followers.empty?
    assert_match @user.followers.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.followers.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user the standard way" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path, followed_id: @other.id
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user with Ajax" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      xhr :post, relationships_path, followed_id: @other.id
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user the standard way" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user with Ajax" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      xhr :delete, relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end
end
```

---

### NOT WORKING: AJAX BUTTONS

Then in **[Section 12.2.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax)** of the Tutorial we are told to switch the following files like this to enable an Ajax follow/unfollow button:

**_follow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**_unfollow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**relationships_controller.rb**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

The following two files are created:

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

The writer than says:

> With that, you should navigate to a user profile page and verify that
>   you can follow and unfollow without a page refresh.

No dice.

There are 4 test errors when running `bundle exec rake test`:

```
ERROR["test_should_unfollow_a_user_with_Ajax", FollowingTest, 2015-11-13 14:40:53 -0500]
 test_should_unfollow_a_user_with_Ajax#FollowingTest (1447443653.75s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users__follow_html_erb___290914909715466310_2191384660'
            app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__follow_html_erb___290914909715466310_2191384660'
            app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_destroy_js_erb___2680666598962148369_2191775880'
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
        app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users__follow_html_erb___290914909715466310_2191384660'
        app/views/users/_follow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__follow_html_erb___290914909715466310_2191384660'
        app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_destroy_js_erb___2680666598962148369_2191775880'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'

ERROR["test_should_follow_a_user_with_Ajax", FollowingTest, 2015-11-13 14:40:53 -0500]
 test_should_follow_a_user_with_Ajax#FollowingTest (1447443653.81s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__unfollow_html_erb__1207823279820701916_2213161380'
            app/views/relationships/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_create_js_erb__279097861293830543_2213276120'
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
        app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__unfollow_html_erb__1207823279820701916_2213161380'
        app/views/relationships/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_create_js_erb__279097861293830543_2213276120'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'

ERROR["test_should_follow_a_user_the_standard_way", FollowingTest, 2015-11-13 14:40:53 -0500]
 test_should_follow_a_user_the_standard_way#FollowingTest (1447443653.86s)
ActionController::ActionControllerError:         ActionController::ActionControllerError: Cannot redirect to nil!
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in create'
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in create'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'

ERROR["test_should_unfollow_a_user_the_standard_way", FollowingTest, 2015-11-13 14:40:54 -0500]
 test_should_unfollow_a_user_the_standard_way#FollowingTest (1447443654.06s)
ActionController::ActionControllerError:         ActionController::ActionControllerError: Cannot redirect to nil!
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in destroy'
            app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in destroy'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'

  76/76: [==================================] 100% Time: 00:00:10, Time: 00:00:10

Finished in 10.29205s
76 tests, 312 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

The official Tutorial's github is here: https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. While your snippets reflect this change, for me the issue was Hartl does not do a snippet highlight for one of the key changes he makes in `relationships_controller.rb` (he does talk about it in the text, which I was skimming at this point in the tutorial).

The change is that`user` goes from regular variable to an instance variable. So:

```
user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
```

becomes

```
@user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
```

Once I added that change, the `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` error was resolved.